# Zulu on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: azul-zulu, azure-zulu

Recently Microsoft has released the GA version of Windows Server 2012 R2. One can also create a VM in Azure with this OS. Does Zulu support this OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 R2 is supported in recent release based on 7u45, see http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu/downloads